# Skyrim will not start and forces me to hard reboot my computer

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

When I play Skyrim from Steam it launches the menu, and that works fine. The problem is when I hit play it closes the launcher (as if it were about to go into the game), and then nothing, just the Windows loading icon instead of my mouse cursor. After about a minute of nothing my computer bogs up, and I am forced to do a hard reset (essentially crashes it) otherwise I am unable to do anything.

My drivers are up to date. I have tried repairing the files with Steam, changing to sound properties, and even copying all of the files from my laptop where Skyrim does work on (even that did not work). Also note that this is not a CTD (Crash To Desktop) error, this is Skyrim not even starting up at all (apart from the launcher), and forcing me to restart my computer. This problem has been going on ever since I bought the game.

Comment: A few questions to get more detail: Are you sure your PC meets the requirements? Do you have any mods? Is it possible some anti-virus software is blocking the game execution?

Comment: Anti-virus could be the problem I will check. I do meet the requirements, and it was doing this even before I had mods installed so that is not the problem.

Comment: Have you tried running it through SKSE?

Comment: Made sure my anti-virus was allowing it, and it still did not work.

Comment: Yes, it still does the same thing and I am forced to hard reboot my PC.

Comment: It was a missing .dll file, I just copied the one that was missing into the Skyrim folder next to the other .dll files and it worked!

Comment: Nice. Next time, maybe a Steam Validation would have caught that, in case you have a similar problem with any other game! You might want to format your solution as an answer so others having the same problem can benefit as well.